# How can I find the solution set to this equation?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Consider the following general equality: 
$$
a_1 = (s_0 + a_0 + s_1) \mod 89
$$
where $a_1, a_0 \in [0, 89]$ are real numbers, and $s_0, s_1$ are positive real values such that $s_0 < s_1$.  My question is as follows: given $a_1, s_1$, are there a finite or uncountably infinite number of $(s_0, a_0)$ pairs that would satisfy the equality?  Would you be able to help me determine the solution set of possible $s_0, a_0$ values for a given $a_1, s_1$?

Comment: What do you mean by mod for real numbers?

Comment: @BillDubuque I mean remainder still, that is, $89.592 \mod 89 = 0.592$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the proprieties of modulus, we can write
$$a+k\equiv b+k \mod n$$
So, we can write:
$$a_1-s_1\equiv a_0+s_0 \mod 89$$
So, we want to find two quantities, such that:
$$*a_0+s_0)x-89y=a_1-s_1$$
where $(x,y)\in Z$.

We know that the set of real number ($R$) is infinite and uncountable. So, also the tuples $(a_0,s_0)$ that belongs to $R×R$ are infinite and uncountable.

Comment: Thank you, just to make sure I am not misunderstanding, I take it the $*$ you wrote should be a $($, and there are an uncountably infinite variety of potential solutions?

Comment: @GEG: you are right, there are infinite many possible solutions.